# What is infinite limit of rational trigonometric function?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How can we justify the following limit?
$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}  \dfrac{1+\cos x}{3+2\cos x}
$$

We can see the result of limit DNE or $[0, 2]$ on the graph. How can we show?

Comment: "limit DNE or $[0, 2]$" : what does this signify?

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @user2661923 I guess DNE is "doesn't exist"

Comment: $~\cos(x)~$ is periodic, with period equal to $~2\pi.~$  Is the function $~\dfrac{1 + \cos(x)}{3 + 2\cos(x)}~$ periodic $~$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given function is bounded. It has as its minimum $0$ and as its maximum $\frac 25$.
In fact

$$0=\frac{0}{1}\leq \frac{1+\cos \:x}{3+2\cos \:x}\leq \frac{1+1}{3+2}=\frac{2}{5}=0.4,\quad \forall x \in \Bbb  R$$

[image]

Hence the limit $$\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}  \dfrac{1+\cos x}{3+2\cos x}$$ not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @RamazanÖzarslan You're welcome.